# React Datepicker - prevent range with disabled dates in between

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using [react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-date-range) for a booking system.

I am using `filterDate` to disable some dates.

```
<DatePicker
    selected={startDate}
    onChange={changeRangeHandler}
    startDate={startDate}
    endDate={endDate}
    selectsRange
    placeholderText={'Choisir vos dates'}
    minDate={new Date()}
    maxDate={addMonths(new Date(), bookingThreshold)}
    disabled={!regexNum.test(numPersons)}
    locale="fr"
    filterDate={isNotDisabled}
/>
```

The filtering function:

```
const isNotDisabled = (date) => {
    return !disabledDates.includes(moment(new Date(date)).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
```

`disabledDates` is a state array that is being updated dynamically.

Since this is for a booking system, once the user selects a check-in date, he should not be able to select a check-out that include disabled dates in between.

I have not seen anything about that particular issue in the documentation or on other posts on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `excludeDates` prop. https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-exclude-dates

Comment: `excludeDates` still let me select a range with disabled dates in between

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a similar calendar. You should create your own function to remove the disabled dates in a range, there's not a native prop to do this

I created two big functions, `getCheckInDates` and `getCheckOutDates`. When calendar is opened, getCheckInDates is triggered. I just enable check in dates. Then, when you select the first date, it triggers `getCheckOutDates`.

I have an array with all dates. First, i removed all previous dates to `check in` (in my case, i have an object and there's a property with the date in it, and that's why i'm doing two loops. Maybe isn't the best way, but works for me. Should be simpler for you)

```
 // Can't select previous days to Check-In
  const removeBeforeDates = availability?.total_availabilities?.filter(el => isAfter(new Date(el?.availability_date.replaceAll(/-/g, "/")), new Date(startDate)));
  const dates = [];

  removeBeforeDates.length > 0 && removeBeforeDates.map(el => {
    const date = new Date(el.availability_date.replaceAll(/-/g, "/"));
    dates.push(date);
  });
```

Now you have an array with all the enable dates starting from `check in` date. Now, find the first disabled date, and shrink the array one day before. **i think that this is what you're looking for**

```
  // if found an unavailable date in the range, shrink firts part of range
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    const currentDate = new Date(dates[i]);
    const nextDate = new Date(dates[i + 1]);
    const diff = differenceBetweenDays(currentDate, nextDate);
    
    results.push(currentDate);
    
    if (diff !== 1) {
      break;
    }
  }

  setIncludeDates(results);
```

> Note: I'm using `isAfter` function from `date-fns` and i've created a helper function to calculate difference between days

```
export const differenceBetweenDays = (a, b) => {
  const date_a = new Date(a);
  const date_b = new Date(b);

  const differenceStamp = date_b.getTime() - date_a.getTime();
  const difference = Math.ceil(differenceStamp / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  return difference;
};
```

Excuse my english!